# How to reference a user related to entry input in if statement

Tags: templating, craft3, users

I am having trouble referencing a user in an if statement:

```
{% set otherEntry = craft.entries().section('other').userFieldInOtherEntry("{externalVariable}").one() %}

{% if currentUser is relatedTo(otherEntry) %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

I've tried using the for loop method described in the Craft 3 documentation, but I get a recursive loop error.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```twig
{% set otherEntry = craft.entries().section('other').userFieldInOtherEntry("{externalVariable}").one() %}

{% if currentUser in otherEntry.userFieldInOtherEntry %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you Oli, I'll try this solution out and see how it works.

Comment: This suggestion didn't work.  I'll post what ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to go through a for loop checking if the user is related to the current entry, then if statements inside of that for loop.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
{% if currentUser.isInGroup('userGroup') %}
<p>My Things:</p>
{% set relatedThings = craft.entries.section('things').relatedTo(currentUser) %}
<ol>
    {% for rel in relatedThings if rel.createdFieldinThing == externalVariable %}
    <li>{{rel.title}} - {{rel.createdFieldinThing}}
        {% if rel.createdFieldinThing == externalVariable %}
                the current user is in the thing
            {% else %}
                the current user is not in the thing
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
</ol>
{% endif %}
```